# TFBuild Local File Copy

Tags: macos, cordova, tfs, build, azure-devops

I'm facing problems using TFBuild in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online).

I want to use the Copy Files task before running Cordova tasks, to copy certificates from a local folder into the build folder (or any folder that Cordova Build can access, it has to be relative to the repository)

I am using the following configuration:
[Step Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYHe1.png)

But what happens is, that it creates a folder with the name $(build.artifactsstagingdirectory) in user/****/myagent/_work/build/****/ instead of using the content of the variable as the path.

Tried with several variables, always creates a folder with the name of the variable. Tried with upper/lower/camel/pascal Case but it did not change anything.

The source files are copied into that folder.

Docs don't seem to do something different.

log does not say anything besides:

> 2016-07-20T11:58:20.550Z: found 1 files
>
> 2016-07-20T11:58:20.551Z: Copying /Users/****/certs/android/release/xxxx.keystore to $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/xxxx.keystore

The Build-Agent is a Mac Mini, with OS X 10.11.6

Am I doing something wrong or is it a Bug?

Debug log says:
http://prntscr.com/bxn6s6

Had to add a picture, wouldn't let me post it with line breaks otherwise.

Comment: Can you add a powershell script task with "Get-ChildItem Env:" command in it to check the environment variables during the build?

Comment: As i am using a mac for Building, powershell is not available.

Comment: Is there a blank space between "$" and “(" in your debug log? And can you share the steps how do you configure the build agent?

Comment: No, there is no blanked, neither in config nor in the logs. The step configuration is in the screenshot above, it doesn't even work if i only do this one step.

Comment: Did you configure it by following the steps here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/blob/master/docs/start/startosx.md?

Comment: well i did not load it from github, i got it from my VSO directly, but yea looks quite similar. started it as an agent

Comment: Are you using the 2.104.0 version from VSTS? I will try it at my side to see if I can get the same behavior.

Comment: I cannot tell which version I have, I can't find any version in the configuration center. As i am using VSO i guess i always have the newest?

Comment: Any idea? :/ Did not find any solution yet

Comment: No, I configured a OSX agent and run a test with predefined variables, it works correctly.

Comment: And I would recommend you to add a "Shell" task with "env" command to check the environment variables during build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple. The Build Agent was outdated.
With the current version (which had huge installation problems due to openSSL deprecation on Mac OS) it works fine.